# How to query to JSON column in a postgres table , to retrieve all the values from all json for a particular json key

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We are using postgres , in that we had a table containing column of type of JSON , in that we have below type of JSON documents ,

please find sample [here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/tk2z6)

i want all the values of json key `student_id` from all the JSON docum

i mean we have such documents , for each row for that column and each document contains contains that JSON key , am trying to get all the values for that json key from all the documents(all rows for that column)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `json_array_elements`.
Find everything you need in the [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) page.

For your sample you could do something like this:

```
select json_array_elements(json_array_elements('{
"srs_student_information": {
    "header": {
        "name": "kkkk"
    },
    "beginning_segment": {
        "age": 12
    },
    "loop_id_sls": [{
        "student_level_details": {
            "class": "12"
        },
        "parent_details": [{
            "name": "assa"
        }],
        "student_identification": [{
            "student_id_qual": "BM",
            "student_id": "00547311"
        }, {
            "student_id_qual": "CN",
            "student_id": "467931496024"
        }, {
            "student_id_qual": "CN",
            "student_id": "467931496035"
        }, {
            "student_id_qual": "CN",
            "student_id": "467931496046"
            }]
        }]
    }
}'::json->'srs_student_information'->'loop_id_sls')->'student_identification')->>'student_id' student_id
```